When should I do characteristic selection?
I am running some Machine Learning algorithms in order to train a model.
Until now I've been doing a correlation matrix in order to select the characteristics with highest correlaction to my target variable.
I read online that doing this selection is not necessary unless I am running Logistic Regression. Is this true?
The algorithms that I am running are Logistic Regression, Decision Tree, SVM, KNN and Naive Bayes.
Should I use my training set with all the characteristics for all the algorithms except Logistic Regression and another version with only the most correlated variables for Logistic Regression?

Well, as always, depends on your data. I would say that if you have enough data, every model (including logistic regression) should be able to "learn" which are the important features and which are not. For example, if you are using sklearn you can try using the feature_imoortance method after training the model, you'll see that you get a result similar to that one that you got in the correlations.
If you have little data I guess it could be a good regularisation technique, since it's a way to remove noise.
If possible I would try to always use all features without taking it to the extreme. That is, if I'm trying to predict, for example, the prices of houses and I have a feature that is how fast did each marathoner ran the last marathon I would definitely drop that column.

will it be a good idea to use feature_importance after training the model, create a new dataset with only the features returned by feature_importance and train the model again with that new dataset?

Not gonna lie to you, I've never tried that. I guess it kinda makes sense? You could try it, I'm guessing that it should work as a regularisation technique, but not sure
